# How to implement streaming upload from Window Phone 7 to PC

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, rest, tcp, windows-phone-7.1

Im trying to implement streaming upload of files (~10 MB) from a Windows Phone 7-client to a PC-server. I have tried the following methods:

1. REST WCF and WebRequest POST -> failed because AllowWriteStreamBuffering and SendChunked are missing from HttpWebRequest in the WP7 API.
2. WCF with MessageContract and Stream -> failed because Stream was changed to byte[] by the service proxy generator on the client app.

Now Im thinking of using one of the following:

1. Custom data chunking and some kind of StartNewTransfer/SendChunk/CompleteTransfer-pattern with WCF.
2. Streaming with TCP (WP7.1)

My questions:

- Will streaming WCF or REST upload be working in WP7.1 or should they allready be working with WP7? (-> I could be doing something wrong)
- What other options do I have?
- Which method would you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

I think custom chunking would be best as you don't know what network limitations a device might have.  Break the file into 100kb chunks and post it to a webservice of your choice.  It might be also worth hashing each chunk on the device and sending the hash through first so you can validate each recieved chunk as correct (just in case)